# How to create a thread that lasts for a minute and takes input via button listener in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on an Android application in which I allow the users to enter text as many time they want in a single minute. But the thread is not terminating after a minute. My code:

public void startTimer(View view) throws Exception {

```
    final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextInput);
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
              myButton.setOnClickListener( 
                  new Button.OnClickListener() { 
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                Log.d("Tag", mEdit.getText().toString());
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();

    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            t.interrupt();
        }
    },1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

better use CountDownTimer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html 
In your solution you try do something with UI state in not main thread - this can be a issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread isn't "taking input".  It's continuously making and installing new onClick listeners.

You don't need a thread for what you're trying to do.  You need a timer that goes off after one minute, and you need a listener that either accepts the input or rejects it depending on whether the timer has gone off yet or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions you can do:

**1st Solution:**

You can simply use a handler.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        t.interrupt();
    }
}, 60000);
```

**2nd Solution:**

You can also use a CountDownTimer.

```
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        t.interrupt();
    }
}.start();
```